# How to get the first version of all files in a S3 directory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I override an S3 directory (with 500 files) by mistake and all the files in that S3 directory have two versions. I need to upload the data to Redshift (both the first version and second version), is there a way using CLI? Or is there a way that I can copy the first version into a different S3 directory?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to write something yourself. The earlier version is only accessible by calling `GetObjectVersions()` on each object individually.

You could write a script that iterates through each object, calls `GetObjectVersions()`, then accesses the earlier version, or copies the earlier version to a new location.

Look at the bright side: At least versioning was activated, so you didn't lose any data!